How to hide `country` and other fields from a domain `whois` information which registrar is Squarespace?
Squarespace acquired Google Domains domains a few months ago. Not so happy about that, but this is another story.
Now, a whois on my domains says for most fields
Redacted for privacy

which is good.
However country, state and organization still show the actual value. That's part of Squarespace privacy policy (Why would they show that information while most registrars don't is a mystery to me)

If your registrar is Squarespace Domains LLC or Squarespace Domains II LLC, your state or province, country, and organization name (if one is provided) will show

Anyway, I couldn't find a setting or some other way to hide that information in Squarespace settings. But a user was talking about a "form" that would maybe allow to do that(?).
Is there some "advanced customization" in Squarespace that might allow to change how whois information is presented?

You could try to edit the information to show something different or switch registrars.

Legally, one should not "lie" about their personal information. It's one way to lose a domain name... It seems that, indeed, switching registrars is the only way to "hide" personal data :-(
